# How to view the Particular view controller when user click the notification IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, apple-push-notifications

I have added push notification in my application and I want to view particular ViewControllers when the user enables PushNotifications but its going to the main view controller only i have tried some methods its not working. Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    updatepoliticalViewController *ringingVC = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"updatepoliticalViewController"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ringingVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
```

My didFinishMethod:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)];
        return YES;
  }
```

My view controller name is `updatepoliticalViewController` this is the view controller where i want to go when user click the notification i have used a navigation view controller in the `updatepoliticalViewController`. Please tell where I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that you are clicking the notification and expecting a view controller to be opened. Have you tried the above code in - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application ?

Comment: @joe no i did't tried that method

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : `Maintain` a `flag` in `AppDelegate` ie create`bool isNotified;` Also a `property` for it;

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

   //need validation then add here as such these notification should only open new view controller
   self.isNotified = TRUE;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  if(self.isNotified)
  {
     //add your viewcontroller here to UIWindow
  }
  self.isNotified = NO;

}
```

Comment: in isNotified its showing like property is not found

Comment: Create a property for it

Comment: please tell me the property is this is nstring or which one i have to give

Comment: its bool check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
{
    NSLog(@"notification Alertbody message:::%@",notif.alertBody);


    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        viewcontroller *slideViewController = [[viewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navl=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:slideViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController=navl;
        [slideViewController release];
    }
    else if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        NSLog(@"notification Alertbody message:::%@",notif.alertBody);

    }

}
```

Comment: i have tried ur code its not working im using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `didReceiveRemoteNotification`  instead of `didReceiveLocalNotification`:

try this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
   //...

   NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
   if(userInfo){
      //Do something with userInfo for notification, in this case app is closed when receive remote notification.
      updatepoliticalViewController *ringingVC = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"updatepoliticalViewController"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ringingVC animated:YES completion:NULL];

   }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
     if(application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive){
       //Do something with userInfo for notification, in this case app is in background when receive remote notification.
       updatepoliticalViewController *ringingVC = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"updatepoliticalViewController"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:ringingVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
     }
}
```

Comment: @simelone please check my didfinish method i have updated in my question

Comment: @user3427551 you `didfinish` code is necessary, and add my post code below `register` method, to deal with receiving remote notification when app doesn't launch.

Comment: please tell wt ihave do inside teh if(userinfo) method

Comment: I have edited my answer, in `if(userinfo)` do anything you want to to when receive notification.

Comment: ihave used ur code its not working its not event opeing the application when i click the notification its crashing the app

Comment: Is the `ringingVC` not nil? Do you know how to set a breakpoint?

Comment: im new to the ios development